# Amazon Kinesis vs AWS Manage Service Kafka (MSK) - (Connect from on-prem)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis, aws-msk

I'm evaluating AWS Kinesis vs Managed Service Kafka (MSK). Our requirement is sending some messages (JSON) to AWS to from the on-prem system (system develop using c++). Then we need to persist above messages into the relational database like PostgreSQL, and same time we need to stream above data into some other microservices (java) which hosted in AWS.

I have the following queries:

i) How can I access(connect and send messages) to AWS Kinesis from my on-premise system? Is there any C++ API supporting that? (There are java client API, but our on-prem system written on C++)

ii) How can I access(connect and send messages) to AWS MSK from my on-premise system?

iii) Is it possible to integrate MSK with other AWS service (e.g lambda, Redshift, EMR, etc)?

iv) To persist data into a database can we use AWS lambda? (AWS Kinesis supporting that functionality, what about AWS MSK)

v) Our message rate is 50msg/second and what is the cost-effective solution?

Comment: For iii: consider confluent replicator to mirror on-prem brokers/topics to a cloud cluster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be blunt, your use case sounds simple and 50 messages a second is a very low rate.

Kinesis is a firehose where you need a straw.  Kinesis is meant to ingest, transform and process terabytes of moving data. ]

Have you considered rather looking at SQS or Amazon MQ ?  Both are considerably simpler to use and manage than Kafka or Kinesis.  Just from your questions it's clear you have not interacted with Kafka at all, so you're going to have a steep learning curve.  SQS is a simple api-based queueing system - you publish to an SQS queue, and you consume from the queue.  If you don't need to worry about ordering, routing, etc it is a persistent and reliable (if clunky) technology that lots of people use to great success.

To answer your actual questions:

1. Amazon publishes a C++ SDK for their services - I would be stunned if there wasn't a Kinesis client as part of this.  You would either need a public Kinesis endpoint, or a private Kinesis endpoint accessible via some sort of tunnel or gateway between your on-prem network and your AWS vpc.
2. MSK is Kafka.  You need an Apache Kafka C++ client, and similar to kinesis above you will need some sort of tunnel or gateway from your on-prem network to the AWS vpc where you have provisioned MSK
3. It's possible, but it's unlikely there are any turn-key solutions for this.  You will have to write some sort of bridging software from Kafka -> Other systems
4. You can possibly use Lambda, so long as you cater for failures, timeouts, and other failure modes.  To be honest, a stand-alone consumer running as a service in your vpc or on-prem is a better idea.
5. SQS or Amazon MQ as previously mentioned are likely to be simpler and more cost-effective than MSK, and will almost certainly be cheaper than Kinesis.

Comment: Absolutely right: great answer.  Two further points relating to both MSK and Amazon MQ: these are both the AWS-integrated implementations of open source tools.  The primary intent of AWS is to provide a migration path for existing implementations.  Kinesis and SQS (and actually SNS) are the full AWS implementations.  We would expect them to get updates, more support, fuller integration, etc. over time.